# Invalid form when uploading file in Django

Tags: html, django

I need to upload file on a Django page, however, after following the official tutorial, I was not able to upload it, it always gives the error "invalid form", and when I tried to print out the error msg of the form, it says "This field is required".

One thing notable is: I have 2 forms on one page, one is this `upload form` and the other one is for filling out `information`. Not sure if this is the root cause.

I have tried all solutions provided on the Internet.

Template file:

```html
<form id="uploadForm" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="file" value="upload" name="sourcefile">
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

Forms.py:

```py
from django import forms
from .models import SourceFile

class UploadFileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SourceFile
        fields = ('file', 'title')
```

Models.py:

```py
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class SourceFile(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="media/")
```

Views.py

```py
def model_form_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = SourceFile(file_field=request.FILES['file'])
            instance.save()
            return JsonResponse({'error': False, 'message': 'Uploaded Successfully!'})
        else:
            print("Invalid form")
            # return JsonResponse({'error': True, 'errors': form.errors})
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(request, 'source_validation.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: why adding <input type="file"> if you already have {{ form.as_p }}? Don't you see 2 input fields here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your template is wrong. Either use `{{ form.as_p }}` which should display a file input field because `file` is a field in your form. (so remove the `<input type="file" ...>`)

Or don't use it and manually add the `<input>` fields, but then you must use the correct names. Your form expects a "file" parameter, not a "sourcefile" parameter:

```
<input type="file" name="file">
```

Also, you're overcomplicating things in your view (even though your current code will work if you fix your template):

```
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()  # this will save your model
    return redirect(...)
```

Comment: well, it is still not working when manually using the `<input>` field. Giving the error: **django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: App_sourcefile**

Comment: You havent migrated?

Comment: oh, yes, forgot that... it worked now! Great thanks to you!